# Create Case feed layout from a regular page layout

Tags: case, page-layout, feed-based-layout

I have a normal Case page layout (by normal, i mean its not a feed layout).

Is it possible to get a feed layout from that just by cloning? I tried cloning it, but what you get after cloning is also a regular page layout.

How do i get a feed layout from that regular page layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore it. I got it.

Its as simple as clicking on "New" page layout. Then it gives the option of which existing page layout to clone from, and whether you want it to be a feed layout or not.